# R | update column in dataframe based on conditions in other dataframe

Tags: r

I am having trouble finding a way to cleaning update the amount column in table 1 with the price column in table 2. I know that left_join and merge could be used to join the price column, rename it, and then drop it, but I am wondering if there is simpler way to avoid creating a mess.

I should state that the real dataset is more complicated and that the amount column in table 1 needs to be conditionally updated somehow based on table 2.

Table 1

| Fruit | Vegetable | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | broccoli |  |
| pear | spinach |  |
| pineapple | carrot |  |

Table 2

| Fruit | Vegetable | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | broccoli | 10 |
| pear | spinach | 5 |
| pineapple | carrot | 2 |

Comment: Have you tried `merge` ? `merge(table1, table2, by = c('Fruit', 'Vegetable'))`

Comment: @Ronak Shah then i am left with having to rename the price column to amount and drop the original amount column that would still be blank. I would prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use `merge` and update process you can use `match`.

```
table1$amount <- table2$price[match(paste(table1$Fruit, table1$Vegetable),
                                    paste(table2$Fruit, table2$Vegetable))]
```

Comment: that works. I can turn it into a function and apply it across multiple columns now. Thank you!